# Finding 3-Sigma given 10 values and 1-Sigma

Tags: statistics

I have 10 values and the 1-Sigma at hand. What are the various methods to find 3-Sigma with these 10 values and/or 1-Sigma?

Is it as simple as multiplying the sigma by three and subtracting it from the mean? Are there any exceptions or things to be careful about?

Comment: Where are you stuck? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: How are you defining $3$ sigma?  Why isn't it just $3$ times $1$ sigma?

Comment: I am new to the topic. @RossMillikan Is it just as easy as to multiply it by three? I didn't think so. And this is all I got. I'm looking for a general formula that can be applied to any 10 values and 1-Sigma to find 3-Sigma.

Answer (score 0):

Given a list of ten numbers, you can compute the standard deviation in the usual way
$$\sigma=\sqrt{\overline {x^2}-(\overline x)^2}$$
$3 \sigma$ is just three times this.